# calling XQueryKeymap() function in pygtk?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

How do I call the x [XQueryKeymap](http://www.sbin.org/doc/Xlib/chapt_09.html)() function in a pygtk application?

Answer (score 1):

[XQueryKeymap()](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XQueryKeymap.html) is very low-level and inherently non-portable, since it returns `an array of bytes that identifies which keys are pressed down. Each bit represents one key of the keyboard.` Of course, you don't get to decide *which* bit identifies *which* key on *which* platform, for it would spoil the fun.

Both GTK+ and Python aim for better portability, that's why that function was [already frowned upon](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2003-October/msg00311.html) way back in 2003.

You might want to use [gtk.gdk.Keymap](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkkeymap.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you.  I am not sure how to use those Keymap functions to query if CTRL is down when my activity gets focus.  I was hoping to use XQueryKeymap() to determine that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @jedierikb, if your activity gets focus from mouse clicks, one way would be to use the `state` member of the `Event` object to check for modifier keys. See http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-EventHandling.html.